# Remote Desktop Connection Manager

Tags: batch-file, vpn, remote-desktop

I am using Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.2

Do u guys know if there's a way to run a .bat/.cmd script (e.g. vpn script) before connecting to a VM?

I have a bat script to connect to Juniper VPN. I wish rdcman run it automatically before   connecting so that I wouldn't have to run it every time manually.

Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start Remote Desktop Connection manager from the "VPN" batch file, by appending the following command to your batch file:

```
mstsc /v VMNAME
```

This will launch a session with `VMNAME`.